# How to simulate _moz_resizing in Chrome or Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So I want to image-resize client side, just like this, but not only in Firefox.

[image: StackOverflow logo image resizing]

Notice that the element generated in Firefox, has the attribute `_moz_resizing = "true"`.

[image: code generated in Firefox]

The code is as simple as the following.

```js
document.querySelector('p').contentEditable = true;
```

```html
<p>
  <img src='http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png' alt='stackoverflow icon'>
</p>
```

**Is there any way to do this for Chrome and Edge too?.** I you are going to provide a solution in JavaScript, I would like better if it's vanilla.js than jQuery. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in chrome by wrapping the image with a div and adding this styles..

```
resize: both; 
overflow: auto;
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/anwar3606/d184oqfz/

**JQuery UI**

JQuery UI provides very good resizability functions and is very easy to use.
https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#default

Comment: Thank you for your response. Few things I didn't like about this solution. First It doesn't work on Edge, second it works in Chrome but I can't resize down (downscale) the image, only make it bigger. In Firefox somehow keeps working but even better. So I give you an up vote but still is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Also just noticed that if you hide the scroll (overflow: hidden) it won't resize anymore in Chrome, somehow it keeps working in Firefox...

Comment: I didn't liked my solution too.., please check the answer again.

Comment: Thank you again for your response. I said I would prefer `vanilla.js` (pure JavaScript) than a `JQuery` solution. I think I improved the solution you gave me: https://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/3b5aoq03/ . I fixed the overflow scroll (hidden and still resizing), and as for resizing down, you just need to make initially very small, which is nice if you want to insert it on a paragraph while editing some text. But still can't figure out how to do this work for `Microsoft Edge`, I mean, if `jQuery UI` guys were able to provide a solution in their library, we should be able too, right?

Comment: In 2022 the new Edge has a chrome built-in and now I can confirm that this solution works for resizing, both downscaling and upscaling.